# How to import Patio Library in my Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I found this library in android-arsenal that would fit perfect in my project.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1076

https://github.com/asantibanez/Patio

I tried to import like this:

```
repositories {
   maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.asantibanez:Patio:d11e20326e'
}
```

But I got a error like this

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Artifact 'Patio.jar (com.github.asantibanez:Patio:d11e20326e)' not found.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jitpack.io/com/github/asantibanez/Patio/d11e20326e/Patio-d11e20326e.jar
```

Another thing that I tried was to import by downloading the project zip, and importing it to my project by: File > Import Module. ( Patio-Master folder )

But I got a Gradle error.

```
Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'dealerbook' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Is there a better/right way to import it to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Patio project.
2. Unzip
3. Import module
4. Select folder Patio-master/Patio
5. Finish
6. Edit build.gradle file (Patio one, not your project one)
7. Change the follow line to the same as your project build.gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

8. Comment the follow line in Patio gradle file

```
applicationId "com.andressantibanez.android.patio"
```

9. Go to File > Project Structure > Dependences
10. Click on the (left|plus|add) button on the left bottom
11. Select module dependence
12. Find Patio in it.
13. Now you'r done to use Patio

Answer (score 2):

**Patio** does not support **JitPack** from what I can see: https://github.com/asantibanez/Patio/blob/master/build.gradle

The author need to do some work in order for **JitPack** to work with it: https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/blob/master/BUILDING.md

Open an *issue* or send a *pull request* ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in Patio. It is my library. :D

At the moment, I have not uploaded Patio to any cloud repository (Maven, JitPack, etc) so I would suggest you download the library and import it as a module in your Android Studio project.

I am very interested in uploading it and making Patio available through Gradle. If you could give me any pointers I would try to make it available as a dependency.

Cheers.

Comment: I did it. I liked it very much. 
I did work in a translation to it. (Portuguese) 
Is there any way to message you thought here ? or Git?

Comment: Sure. Send me a message anytime. Cheers.

Is it Ok to post my email here? Or is there another way to get in touch?